# Is there a way to use message in other functions

Tags: discord.js

Is there a way to access message in `bot.on("message", function (message)` from `bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember)`

for instance I want to use let `let vC = bot.voiceConnections.get(Message.guild.id);` inside the voiceStateUpdate to get the the voice connection to play audio files through the bot but it keeps saying that message is undefined. So is there a way to access message in voiceStateUpdate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be more practical to use `newMember.guild.id`:

```
let vC = bot.voiceConnections.get(newMember.guild.id);
```

Comment: Happy to hear that :)